# Excel 14.4.7 - Issue saving "read only" excel spread sheets

Tags: ms-office

When I save “read only” spread sheets that I receive as attachments, excel doesn’t save them *as their original name*. The pop-up window shows the title of the document as “Untitled”. We work with project specific excel files that are constantly being updated. This problem is especially frustrating when we have a specific name that may be long due to the complexity of the project.

is there something I can do to solve this?

Comment: @Buscar웃SD MS Office does run on OS X - we even have a tag for it

Comment: @Mark sorry the way the question is formated, there is no indication of using a Apple product. It might be as well the non Apple MS office.

Comment: Thanks guys. I’m on a Mac Book Pro using Excel 14.7.1. So when I go to “save as” on an excel file that was sent to me, and thus “read only” on arrival, excel isn’t recognizing the file name of the read only file. So, if the file is called “Bob’s Uncle” and I want to save it, it won’t come up as “Bob’s Uncle” rather it’ll come up as “Untitled”. Thanks so much for your help! Joe

Comment: I just tried that and the problem is, in Excel 14.4.7, the file automatically opens, I don’t get that dialogue box. Word however remembers the name of the document you’re trying to save while excel does not. What a pain...

Answer (score 2):

There is a pop up question for you to answer when opening the "read only" file from email attachment.

[image: read only]

You have to select "No" as answer if you plan to modify and save in the "original" name.

If you answer "Yes" it will change the file name when saving.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the problem is occuring when you do double-click an attachment. Outlook saves attachments in a special folder which is read-only for the user (for what reason ever). When you try to save the document, Excel cannot do this and suggests then automatically another location, changing the document name to "Untitled".

If you right-click on the attachment and save this to another location and open it afterwards, you get the right title and can save it as you like.

Comment: That works! So I’ve always got to right click it, then save it somewhere or else. I’m using an email program called Unibox but I didn’t think that would have an impact. ..